# How to retain value of drop down options after form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-select

I have the three drop down option pulling data from database, the state and city selection.The `city select option` using ajax to get the value from database based on `select in state` value, everything works fine on getting value.The `state value` are using `php function to populate` .

The problem is the second select option, which is `city option` not retaining the value in the select options bar after the has form been submitted. (basically it resets) The second problem after submitting the form the select `options of city` does not populate, you need to change the other `option of state` before you can change it on city list.

Been going through many topics and searching but cant find a solution. i think that the values should remain after i reload the page because I used localstorage for categories and state and had no issues even the `city option` have its values inside localstorage only that it does not show inside select option after page has been reloaded.

```
function get_state(){
  global $db;
  $output = '';
  $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM region");
  foreach($results as $state) {
    $output .='<option value="'.$state["pk_i_id"].'">'.$state["s_name"].'</option>';
  }
  return $output;
}

 <form method="GET">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">

      <select name="categories" id="categories" class="btn-sm saveIt">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?=get_categories();?>
      </select>

      <select name="state" id="state" class="btn-sm saveIt">
        <option value=""></option>

        <?=get_state();?>
      </select>

      <select name="city" id="city" class="btn-sm saveIt">
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>


      <button type="submit" id="go">Go</button>


   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      function get_city(){
        var stateID = $('#state').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/parsers/city_list.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {stateID : stateID},
          success: function(data){
            $('#city').html(data);
          },
          error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong with the city list.")
          },
        });
      }
      $('select[name="state"]').change(get_city);
    });
```

And the city_list.php for ajax call

```
<?php
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/init.php';
  $stateID = (int)$_POST['stateID'];

  $cityQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE fk_i_region_id = '$stateID' ");
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <?php while($city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cityQuery)): ?>
    <option value="<?=$city['pk_i_id'];?>"><?=$city['s_name'];?></option>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

thank in advance if you need some detail i can provide.Thank you.

[A link to sample code](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Store-Form-Values-Into-Local-Storage-saveIt.html)!

This link to jQuery plugin with localstorage. [jquery plugin][1].

Display before submitting form was fine only after submitting the form `city option` displays value instead of `name of value`.

Second issues after submitting form it only shows one option, its supposed to show all option, you need to change `city options` first then all `city list` will shown.

[Problem two image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGAWT.png)

Comment: you know what was submitted in your php, so do all this server side when those values exist

Comment: everything fine for submitting, only the problem to show on html the name of value after page reloading.since i'm new this fields.mostly the problem when comes about ajax or jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ANOTHER NEW VERSION***

OK, I just went ahead and made a working demo without a Database so I could try and understand your issue better. Copy this to your local machine and check it out and see if it is the kind of thing you are looking for. If it works the way you want, let's see if we can adjust to meet your needs with your Database calls.

First, the index.php file:

```
<?php

$states = [
  0 => [
    'pk_i_id' => 0,
    's_name' => 'Montana'
  ],
  1 => [
    'pk_i_id' => 1,
    's_name' => 'Nebraska'
  ],
  2 => [
    'pk_i_id' => 2,
    's_name' => 'Idaho'
  ],
];

function get_state($states, $selectedID){

  $output = '';

  foreach($states as $state) {
    if ($state['pk_i_id'] == $selectedID) {
      $output .='<option selected value="'.$state["pk_i_id"].'">'.$state["s_name"].'</option>';
    } else {
      $output .='<option value="'.$state["pk_i_id"].'">'.$state["s_name"].'</option>';
    }
  }
  return $output;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form method="GET">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="form-group">

          <select name="categories" id="categories" class="btn-sm saveIt">
            <option value="">Categories</option>
          </select>

          <select name="state" id="state" class="btn-sm saveIt">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <?php 

              if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
                $stateID = $_GET['state'];
              } else {
                $stateID = -1;
              }

            ?>
            <?php echo get_state($states, $stateID); ?>
          </select>

          <select name="city" id="city" class="btn-sm saveIt">
            <option value="">City</option>
            <?php 

              if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
                echo "<input id=\"hiddenInput\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{$_GET['city']}\">";
              }

            ?>
          </select>

          <button type="submit" id="go">Go</button>

       </div>
     </div>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next, the city_list.php file:

```
<?php

  // Montana
  $cityList[0] = [
    0 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 0,
      'city_name' => 'Bozeman'
    ],
    1 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 1,
      'city_name' => 'Helena',

    ],
    2 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 2,
      'city_name' => 'Butte'
    ],
  ];

  // Nebraska
  $cityList[1] = [
    0 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 0,
      'city_name' => 'Omaha'
    ],
    1 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 1,
      'city_name' => 'Hastings',

    ],
    2 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 2,
      'city_name' => 'Lincoln'
    ],
  ];

  // Idaho
  $cityList[2] = [
    0 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 0,
      'city_name' => 'Boise'
    ],
    1 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 1,
      'city_name' => 'Twin Falls',

    ],
    2 => [
      'pk_i_id' => 2,
      'city_name' => 'Caldwell'
    ],
  ];

  ob_start();
  ?>
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <?php foreach ($cityList[$_REQUEST['stateID']] as $city) {?>
    <?php if ($_REQUEST['selected'] == $city['pk_i_id']) : ?>
      <option selected value="<?=$city['pk_i_id'];?>"><?=$city['city_name'];?></option>
    <?php else: ?>  
      <option value="<?=$city['pk_i_id'];?>"><?=$city['city_name'];?></option>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php } ?>

<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Finally, script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function get_city(selected) {
    var stateID = $('#state').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'city_list.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {stateID : stateID, selected : selected},
      success: function(data){
        $('#city').html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong with the city list.")
      },
    });
  }

  $('select[name="state"]').change(function () {
    get_city(-1);
  });

  if ( $('select[name="state"]').val() != '') {
    var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
    if (!!hiddenInput) {
      get_city(hiddenInput.value);
    } else {
      get_city(-1);
    }
  }

});
```

Put all of those in the same directory, then check out the functionality. If that is in line with what you need, lets adjust this for your project!

Comment: thank for answer, yes the value remain even after refresh,$cityString only id form $city,i want to show the name of value. the second problem for ajax call still persist where show only one selected city instead all of city after page submitted.

Comment: Using your new function incorrectly. Also missing logic to get the other cities to populate that select

Comment: @azraabdullah I re-wrote my answer, see if it suits your needs now. I think I misunderstood your problem the first time. If that doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder this will return the undefined format_city_for_display() since this function not existed.The function select_city_list() not need since using ajax already fetch the list from database.The $cityDisplay actually can use another function to query database but i think since the ajax already have the return data with value and name.  I edit my question with extra info,hope u guys take a looks, thanks.

Comment: OK, I made another go at it. This is a cool project so I really want to learn from it as well. Just copy what I have into a new directory and run it and see if that does what you expect, then we can tweak for your project. I have to sign off for awhile, but will be back in a few hours.

Comment: yes this what i looking,but i can't implement on my script because the array you using are multi array and select based on array index not the $state= pk_i_id , i'm lost in part of function get_state($states, $selectedID) and mostly part to select data from database.will try again after almost  a day still cant figure..

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder after change little bit on select database now it working. Thank you for your solution .really appreciate. both issues has been solved.